# How do I insert HTML objects between each child object?

Tags: javascript, html

Is this function going to be able to insert li elements in the dashed spaces in the following html code?

```js
    const shoppingList = document.getElementById("shoppinglist");
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    for (let i = 0; i < shoppingList.children.length; i++) {
        shoppingList.insertBefore(li, shoppingList.children[i]);
    
        if (i == shoppingList.children.length - 1) {
            shoppingList.appendChild(li);
        }
    }
```

```html
    <ul id="shoppinglist" class="collection">
        ----
        <li class="collection-item" id="listitem:Where" draggable=true></li>
        ----
        <li class="collection-item" id="listitem:There" draggable=true></li>
        ----
    </ul>
```

Comment: When you run it, does it?

Comment: Show us your output and tell us if it’s what you were looking for.

Comment: I can't help but suspect that the elements you're inserting are presentational, and might be better inserted using CSS pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't.

1. You create only one list element and then are trying to insert it multiple times. You have to create a new element in each iteration.
2. The `shoppingList.children` is constantly updated within the for loop, therefore the condition inside `for(...)` declaration is not going to work as you'd expect.

The following code should work. The difference is, that I take references to only existing list items and try to prepend new list items relative to them. Finally I just append a new list item to the whole tree, therefore I fulfill even the condition when none children are present.

```js
const shoppingList = document.getElementById('shoppinglist')

let i = 0
const createLi = () => {
  const li = document.createElement('li')
  li.innerText = `New ${++i}`
  return li
}

Array.from(shoppingList.children)
  .forEach(c => shoppingList.insertBefore(createLi(), c))
  
shoppingList.appendChild(createLi())
```

```html
<ul id="shoppinglist">
  <li>Original 1</li>
  <li>Original 2</li>
</ul>
```